# Vaadin 7 and applet

Tags: vaadin

0.7 and I want to Call an Applet for use a Token.

I did various tests:
1) Use of AppletIntegration 1.2.9 but when I call applet there's an Exception "ClassNotFoundException PaintTarget"
2) Download Legacy 1.2.10 by https://github.com/Haulmont/AppletIntegration/releases but when I cal the page I have the Exception ""Widgetset does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.applet.AppletIntegration. Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:

org.vaadin.applet.AppletIntegration(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND)" 
3) I create a class AppletCustom

```html
public class AppletCustom extends CustomComponent {
    public AppletCustom(String codebase, 
            String archive, 
            String code,
            String width, 
            String height,
            Map<String, String> params) {
        setCompositionRoot(new Label("<div id='appletDiv'></div>", ContentMode.HTML));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                /* create the applet */
        sb.append("var obj = document.createElement('object');");
        sb.append("obj.setAttribute('type','application/x-java-applet');");
        sb.append("obj.setAttribute('width','" + width + "');");
        sb.append("obj.setAttribute('height','" + height + "');");        
        
        sb.append("var codeParam = document.createElement('param');");
        sb.append("codeParam.setAttribute('name', 'code');");
        sb.append("codeParam.setAttribute('value', '" + code + "');");
        sb.append("obj.appendChild(codeParam);");        
        
        sb.append("var archiveParam = document.createElement('param');");
        sb.append("archiveParam.setAttribute('name', 'archive');");
        sb.append("archiveParam.setAttribute('value','" + archive + "');");
        sb.append("obj.appendChild(archiveParam);");
         
        sb.append("var param = document.createElement('param');");
        sb.append("param.setAttribute('name', 'codebase');");
        sb.append("param.setAttribute('value','" + codebase + "');");
        sb.append("obj.appendChild(param);");
        
        /* add params to the applet if you like */
        if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = 
                    params.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>) it.next();
                sb.append("param = document.createElement('param');");
                sb.append("param.setAttribute('name', '" + pairs.getKey() + "');");
                sb.append("param.setAttribute('value','" + pairs.getValue() + "');");
                sb.append("obj.appendChild(param);");
            }
        }        
        sb.append("document.getElementById('appletDiv').appendChild(obj);");
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

and i Call it in the page. The applet is seen correctly but i must to return a value using the method

```html
vaadinUpdateVariable("docName", docName + SIGNED_FILE_SUFFIX, true);
```

How can i resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

you might have have run into one of two Maven GWT plugin bugs: [MGWT-147][1] or [MGWT-148][2] just like [Henri Sara][3] said .

i recommended this blog for you : [Vaadin addons and maven and eclipse.](http://amanica.blogspot.com/2010/04/vaadin-addons-and-maven-and-eclipse.html)

please read this also : [Using Vaadin with Maven 2](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/43914)

to help you getting your add-on work . if still n't fixed i refer using [Embedded][6]  ui component and avoid the hard coding html tag's.

i wish if i helped you if n't i'm sorry that all i know about Vaadin+applets.

1# jira.codehaus(.)org/browse/MGWT-147

2#jira.codehaus(.)org/browse/MGWT-148

3#vaadin(.)com/c/my_sites/view?groupId=13199&privateLayout=0
4# vaadin(.)com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html